# How to fit a model without an intercept using R tidymodels workflow?

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-parsnip

How can I fit a model using this `tidymodels` workflow?

```
library(tidymodels)
workflow() %>% 
  add_model(linear_reg() %>% set_engine("lm")) %>% 
  add_formula(mpg ~ 0 + cyl + wt) %>% 
  fit(mtcars)
#> Error: `formula` must not contain the intercept removal term: `+ 0` or `0 +`.
```

Comment: seems like you'd need to figure where (and ideally **why**) this restriction is imposed ... working around it could break something downstream, if all of the package machinery is assuming that the intercept is present ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `formula` argument to `add_model()` to override the terms of the model. This is typically used for survival and Bayesian models, so be extra careful that you know what you are doing here, because you are circumventing some of the guardrails of tidymodels by doing this:

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip

mod <- linear_reg()
rec <- recipe(mpg ~ cyl + wt, data = mtcars)

workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(rec) %>%
  add_model(mod, formula = mpg ~ 0 + cyl + wt) %>%
  fit(mtcars)
#> ══ Workflow [trained] ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: linear_reg()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 0 Recipe Steps
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 
#> Call:
#> stats::lm(formula = mpg ~ 0 + cyl + wt, data = data)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>   cyl     wt  
#> 2.187  1.174
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason why this needs a workaround rather than part of the standard workflow?

Comment: Yes. It's a bit long to explain in a comment here, but I'll point you to [this discussion of how the formula is overloaded with multiple purposes in R](https://www.tmwr.org/base-r.html#formula) and how [tidymodels handles the "blueprint" of training data to later be used at prediction time](https://hardhat.tidymodels.org/reference/default_formula_blueprint.html).

Comment: @JuliaSilge would you consider a simpler interface for removing the intercept in a recipe using step_rm?